# How to map a List of Lists from JSON

Tags: json, flutter, list, dart

Let's say I have a `TestObject` object that I am using for a JSON response from my API.

I also have an `A` Object and a `B` object.

Within my `TestObject` response, I am getting a List of Object `A`, but I am getting lists within a List for the `B` objects.

How can I map the list of lists data?

Example code for the TestObject model setup:

```
  class TestObject {
      String? id;
      List<A>? a;
      List<List<B>>? b;
    
      TestObject({
        this.id,
        this.a,
        this.b,
      });
    
      TestObject.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        id = json['id'];
    
        if (json['a'] != null) {
          a = <A>[];
          json['a'].forEach((v) {
            a!.add(A.fromJson(v));
          });
        }
       
        // How do I get b?
      }
    
      Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
        data['id'] = this.id;
    
        final Map<String, dynamic> data = Map<String, dynamic>();
        if (this.a != null) {
          data['a'] = this.a!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
        }
        
        // How do I get b?
        
        return data;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a nested loop.

```dart
b = [];
for(List innerList in json["b"]){
    b.add([]);
    for(var item in innerList){
        b.last.add(B.fromJson(item));
    }
}
```

Also it is not recommended to use `.forEach` with a function literal but to use real for loops instead. (https://dart.dev/tools/linter-rules/avoid_function_literals_in_foreach_calls)

To map it back to JSON something like

```dart
json["b"] = [];
for(List<B> innerList in b){
  json["b"].add([]);
  for(B item in innerList){
    json["b"].last.add(item.toJson())
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, jarinox. What if I need to map it back to JSON?

Comment: Also, this doesn't seem to work. I'm able to see what is in my innerList, but nothing is getting added to b

Comment: If nothing gets added to b there is most likely nothing in `innerList` or `json["b"]`. Try to use the debugger to see the values of e.g. `innerList` at runtime.